# Error conflicting types for function calculatePrice

Tags: c++, c, function

I wrote this coding, then it said that there is an error about [Error] conflicting types for 'calculatePrice'.  I dont know why it appeared to be an error. Can anyone please help me to correct this error? :((

```
void Add(struct data* m[])//, struct data* s)
{
    char cust, choice1, choice2;
    int i, counter = 0;
    double totPrice = 0.00;


    do
    {           
        printf("Member(M) / Student(S) / Regular Customer(R)?");
        scanf("%c", &cust);

        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", &m[counter]->Mname);

        printf("Enter phone number : ");
        scanf("%s", &m[counter]->MphoneNum);

        printf("Enter id : ");
        scanf("%s", &m[counter]->Mid);

        printf("Enter address");
        scanf("%s", &m[counter]->Maddress);

        printf("Enter e-mail : ");
        scanf("%s", &m[counter]->mail);

        do
        {
        /*  totPrice +=*/ calculatePrice(cust);

            printf("Wanna add another order?");
            scanf("%s", choice1);
        }           
        while(choice1 == 'Y');


        counter++;
        m[counter]->payment = totPrice;

        printf("Wanna add another customer?");
        scanf("%s", choice2);
    }

    while(choice2 == 'Y');  
}

double calculatePrice(char cust)
{
    char code[4], size, top;
    double discount, drPrice, topPrice, price;

    if(cust == 'M')
    //searchMember(&m, &s); 
        discount = 0.8;         

    else if(cust == 'S')
        discount = 0.85;

    else if(cust == 'R')
        discount = 0.0;


    printf("Enter the order's code :");
    scanf("%s", code);

    printf("Enter size of cup : ");
    scanf("%s", size);

    printf("Enter topping : ");
    scanf("%s", top);

    if((strcmp(code, "T1")) || (strcmp(code, "T2")) || (strcmp(code, "T3")) ||(strcmp(code, "T4")) || (strcmp(code, "T5")) == 0)
    {
        if(size == 'R')
            drPrice = 4.90;
        else
            drPrice = 5.90;
    }

    else if((strcmp(code, "CH1")) || (strcmp(code, "CH2")) || (strcmp(code, "CH3")) || (strcmp(code, "CH4")) || (strcmp(code, "CH5")) == 0)
    {
        if(size == 'R')
            drPrice = 6.90;
        else
            drPrice = 7.90;
    }

    else if((strcmp(code, "C2")) || (strcmp(code, "C3")) || (strcmp(code, "C5")) == 0)
        drPrice = 5.90;     

    else if((strcmp(code, "S1")) || (strcmp(code, "S2")) || (strcmp(code, "S5")) || (strcmp(code, "S7")) || (strcmp(code, "S9")) == 0)
        drPrice = 6.90;

    else if((strcmp(code, "S3")) || (strcmp(code, "S4")) || (strcmp(code, "S6")) || (strcmp(code, "S8")) || (strcmp(code, "S10")) || (strcmp(code, "S11")) == 0)
        drPrice = 5.90; //check harga balik

    else if((strcmp(code, "C1")) == 0)
        drPrice = 3.90;

    else if((strcmp(code, "C4")) == 0)
        drPrice = 4.90;

    if(top == 'B' || top == 'G' || top == 'J' || top == 'P' || top == 'A')
        topPrice = 0.60;

    else if(top == 'X')
        topPrice = 0.00;

    price = discount * (topPrice + drPrice);

    return price; //return value
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Please show the full code.

Comment: @Kmeixner 125 8 C:\Users\Unit ICT PPDHL\Desktop\New folder\chawan.c [Error] conflicting types for 'calculatePrice'

Comment: Declare function `double calculatePrice(char cust)` before using it to get rid of "conflicting types for 'calculatePrice'"

Comment: `scanf("%s", &m[counter]->Mname);` is very unlikely to be correct, and `(strcmp(code, "C2")) || (strcmp(code, "C3")) || (strcmp(code, "C5"))` is 0 only if `code` is equal to all three strings at once.

Comment: @chux did u mean to declare that function out of the main?

Comment: You have not posted the full code, is there a function prototype? If not it's a "forward reference" and the compiler will make assumptions which in this case (there is a `double`) will be incorrect.

Comment: Yes, declare (or define) the function _before_ `main()`.

Comment: @chux owwwhhhh yess! it's working. thank you so much!! xDD

Answer (score 0):

In that function `calculatePrice`

```
printf("Enter size of cup : ");
scanf("%s", size);

printf("Enter topping : ");
scanf("%s", top);
```

are asking for string input, but the target type is `char`.

Should be

```
printf("Enter size of cup : ");
scanf(" %c", &size);

printf("Enter topping : ");
scanf(" %c", &top);
```

Notice the space before `%c` which will clean off whitespace left after the previous input.

Also please be aware that `char code[4]` can only accept 3 characters. It's a dangerous way to do things as you don't restrict the input length.

Comment: The error you mention would cause undefined behavior, but why would it cause the (presumably) compiler error the OP complains about? If this is C (and not C++, based on `struct data`), the code should still compile even with this error.

Comment: @R_Kapp the latest compilers compare format type with argument?

Comment: @WeatherVane it still has an error eventhough i changed the "%s" to " %c". :((

Comment: C isn't strongly typed, though... even if the comparison is made, my understanding is that you'd get a compiler warning, and not an error.

Comment: Perhaps you have several errors. See @chux comment above.